# Where is the main() method In a JSP/Servlet application?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

The reason I'm asking this is that I want to write code that initializes the application once it starts and cleans up later on.

I dont want to use a servlet `init()` method since it is per servlet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `main()` method in Servlet.

If

> The reason I'm asking this is that I want to write code that initializes the application once it starts and cleans up later on.

You can use [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) implemented

```
public class MyServletContext implements ServletContextListener{
    ServletContext context;
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Context Created");

    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {

        System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.yourpackage.MyServletContext
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `main()` method, because the components are managed and the container invokes other methods - like the `init()` on servlets and filters. The container itself is started through a main method, but even that's hidden from you.

For per-application and initialization you can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

You have to map it in `web.xml` using `<listener><listener-class>...</listener-class></listener>`. In `contextInitialized(..)` and `contextDestroyed(..)` you can do initialization and cleanup respectively.